# Get launchOptions when resuming App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am able to handle the launchOptions value in the `application` method (since, obviously, the parameter gets passed to it). What I'm doing is basically receiving an image from a user who imported it by selecting my app in the *Share* menu:

[image]

It works fine if the App hasn't already been launched, but I don't see how I get the input parameters if the App is already running and the `application` method isn't called.

I tried to find a method that would help me like

`applicationWillEnterForeGround(_ application: UIApplication, _ launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?`

but without any success.

I assume it's possible, since you can share images to WhatsApp or Facebook too, even when they've already been launched.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the `application:openURL:options:` method as follows (Swift 2):

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    // Do your stuff and return true if you have handled the URL...

    // Else
    return false
}
```

[Relevant tutorial in Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/133825/uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial)

As of Swift 4.2 the signature is:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // Do your stuff and return true if you have handled the URL...

    // Else
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're currently watching in the wrong direction. You should refer to [Inter-App communication guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html), provided by Apple. If generalise this, you simply need this method, that will handle URI link to your app.

---

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app 
             openURL:(NSURL *)url 
             options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options;`

Comment: This answer is also correct. I've selected Michael's because he was faster and it's in Swift. Thank you very much!