# Get parameters from URL while not launching app for the first time in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiapplication

we provide some parameters using URL schema and it works well if we launch app for the first time. I have provided a custom initialization in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if let token = Helper.getQueryStringParameter(url: url.absoluteString, param: AUTH_TOKEN_PARAM) {
            tokenFromURL = token
            return true
        } else {
        }
        return false
    }
```

However this code does not work if for instance user downloads app, opens it and **returns back to the web** and presses same button to launch app.

I think I need to check if **URL was provided** in the **viewWillAppear**, am I right? How to do that, please help?

Comment: See the `application(_:,open:,options:)` delegate method.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Get launchOptions when resuming App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015756/get-launchoptions-when-resuming-app?r=SearchResults)